# Cache external images on webserver

Tags: reactjs, flask, webserver

We are showing some images in our iOS App and on our website (react), which are loaded from external websites. The data (json) is provided by our flask back end.

Is there a way to cache the images on our server and only load them from remote when an image is not in the cache?

Comment: The short answer is "yes." Although it may not be of any actual benefit to your users.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be beneficial? The content would come from the same place instead of several servers.

Comment: Why do you believe that's a benefit? The content could be behind a CDN that's faster than your servers. Browsers limit the number of concurrent connections to a single domain. By funneling everything through the same domain, more images get queued rather than just downloading.

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar in an SPA that I worked and personally I would utilize some mechanism such as HTML local storage or `redux` to store the image data. In your `react` container, you can check if you have an image already in your store; if you do then grab it, otherwise retrieve it via some HTTP request (or however) and then store it. I would do this work in `react`'s `componentDidMount` function since I believe this is the preferred location for kicking off such tasks.

I've done similar caching (json data from an Web API) using `redux` and below is very simplified example:

```
// Note: redux actions and state added to props
componentDidMount: function() {
    // check if we have the data in the redux store
    if (this.props.actions.getData && this.props.data != null) {
        this.props.actions.getData();
    }
}
```

The `data` object (or whatever it may be) in my `redux` store's state was placed into in this containers `props`. When the component is mounted, I check if the data was cache (maybe via visiting some other page in my SPA which loaded it). If it was I simply use the data in `this.props.data`, otherwise I call my `redux` action `getData()` which gets the data, places it my store, and initiates a re-render of my `react` component.

Some links:
[Web storage APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)
[Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux)

Comment: For the website that should work, but I wonder if there is a way where both, website and app benefit from.